# YITH WooCommerce Wishlist: Help me show the first item / product thumbnail within the sidebar widget and wishlist manage areas?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, simple-html-dom

I am using YITH Wishlist within WooCommerce, WordPress.

Within an individual wishlist - it displays the image, with 'remove from list', the product title and a link through to the individual product all working.

So going one step higher up the 'folders' when I display the individual wishlists within the Manage Wishlists page, I am only able to show the name of the list and the link through to that individual list where you can see all the products grouped. This is where I wish to be able to display the 'first product within that individual wishlist' 's first image or thumbnail.

I have tried and broken the script numerous times. How can I write a script that will grab that image and let me display it within the Manage Wishlist's page? Better yet, is there a shortcode that does this for me (if there is such a thing)?

Here is the pretty much stock relevant template files...

This is the manage page template (if you Ctrl+F for 'I WANT TO SHOW IMAGE HERE' to see where I want to pull image through) - where I want to display image:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Wishlist manage template
     *
     * @author Your Inspiration Themes
     * @package YITH WooCommerce Wishlist
     * @version 2.0.5
     */
    
    if ( ! defined( 'YITH_WCWL' ) ) {
        exit;
    } // Exit if accessed directly
    ?>
<form id="yith-wcwl-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url( 'manage' ) ) ?>" method="post">
    <!-- TITLE -->
    <?php
        do_action( 'yith_wcwl_before_wishlist_title' );
        
        if( ! empty( $page_title ) ) {
            echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_title', '<h2 class="h1 blue lh2 mt2 mb0 p0">Manage My Boards</h2>' );
        }
        
        do_action( 'yith_wcwl_before_wishlist_manage' );
        ?>
    <table class="shop_table cart wishlist_table wishlist_manage_table" cellspacing="0" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="wishlist-name">
                    <span class="nobr">
                    Boards
                    <?php // echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_manage_name_heading', __( 'Wishlists', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?>
                    </span>
                </th>
                <?php /* ?>
                <th class="wishlist-privacy">
                    <span class="nobr">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_manage_privacy_heading', __( 'Privacy', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?>
                    </span>
                </th>
                <?php */ ?>
                <th class="wishlist-delete">
                    <span class="nobr">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_manage_delete_heading', __( 'Delete', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?>
                    </span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="wishlist-name">
                    <a title="<?php echo $default_wishlist_title ?>" class="wishlist-anchor" href="<?php echo YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url( 'user' . '/' . $current_user_id ) ?>">
                    <?php echo $default_wishlist_title ?>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <?php /* ?>
                <td class="wishlist-privacy">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_manage_default_privacy', __( 'Public', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) )?>
                </td>
                <?php */ ?>
                <td class="wishlist-delete"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $wishlist_count = 0;
                if( ! empty( $user_wishlists ) ):
                ?>
            <?php foreach( $user_wishlists as $wishlist ): ?>
            <?php if( ! $wishlist['is_default'] ): ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="wishlist-name">
                    <a title="<?php echo $wishlist['wishlist_name'] ?>" class="wishlist-anchor" href="<?php echo YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url( 'view' . '/' . $wishlist['wishlist_token'] ) ?>">
                    <!-- I WANT TO SHOW IMAGE HERE (OF THE FIRST PRODUCT IN THE WISHLIST CURRENTLY BEING LOOPED THROUGH) -->
                    <?php echo $wishlist['wishlist_name'] ?>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <?php /* ?>
                <td class="wishlist-privacy">
                    <select name="wishlist_options[<?php echo $wishlist['ID'] ?>][wishlist_privacy]" class="wishlist-visibility selectBox">
                        <option value="0" class="public-visibility" <?php selected( $wishlist['wishlist_privacy'], 0 ) ?> ><?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_public_wishlist_visibility', __( 'Public', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) )?></option>
                        <option value="1" class="shared-visibility" <?php selected( $wishlist['wishlist_privacy'], 1 ) ?> ><?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_shared_wishlist_visibility', __( 'Shared', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) )?></option>
                        <option value="2" class="private-visibility" <?php selected( $wishlist['wishlist_privacy'], 2 ) ?> ><?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_private_wishlist_visibility', __( 'Private', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) )?></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <?php */ ?>
                <td class="wishlist-delete">
                    <!-- <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="wishlist_options[<?php echo $wishlist['ID'] ?>][delete]"/> -->
                    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'wishlist_id', $wishlist['ID'], wp_nonce_url( YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url( 'manage' ), 'yith_wcwl_delete_action', 'yith_wcwl_delete' ) ) ) ?>"><?php _e( 'Delete', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ?></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $wishlist_count ++;
                    endif;
                ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <a class="btn button create-new-wishlist" href="<?php echo YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url( 'create' ) ?>">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_create_new_wishlist_icon', '<i class="icon-plus"></i>' )?>
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_create_new_wishlist_title', __( 'Create a new board', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) )?>
                    </a>
                    <?php if( ! empty( $user_wishlists ) && $wishlist_count ): ?>
                    <button class="submit-wishlist-changes">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_mange_wishlist_icon', '<i class="icon-ok"></i>' )?>
                    <?php _e( 'Save Settings', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ?>
                    </button>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'yith_wcwl_manage_action', 'yith_wcwl_manage' )?>
    <?php do_action( 'yith_wcwl_after_wishlist_manage' ); ?>
</form>
```

This is the individual wishlist page, with the working Show Product Image script (Ctrl+F 'GRABBING THE IMAGE SUCCESSFULLY' to get to relevant code) - where I can see a working example of pulling the image from a product through:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Wishlist page template
     *
     * @author Your Inspiration Themes
     * @package YITH WooCommerce Wishlist
     * @version 2.0.12
     */
    
    if ( ! defined( 'YITH_WCWL' ) ) {
        exit;
    } // Exit if accessed directly
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var root = document.documentElement;
    root.className += ' wishlist-view';
</script>
<?php do_action( 'yith_wcwl_before_wishlist_form', $wishlist_meta ); ?>
<?php
    function cmp($a, $b) {
      if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
      }
      return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    
    uasort($users_wishlists, 'cmp');
    ?>
<?php /* ?>
<pre><code>
  <?php
    print_r($wishlist_items);
    // print_r($users_wishlists);
    ?>
</code></pre>
<?php */ ?>
<!--
<div class="my-materials-sidebar bg-dark-blue white lg:absolute top-0 left-0 bottom-0">
    <div class="bg-darken-3 p2 lg:p3 height-100 overflow-auto">
        <h3 class="h1 mt0">My Materials</h3>
        <h3 class="h2 lg:h1 mb1">My Boards</h3>
        <ul class="list-reset my3 p0 uppercase lg:h3">
            <li><a href="/my-materials/create">Add new board</a></li>
            <li><a href="/my-materials/manage">Manage boards</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list-reset m0 p0 uppercase lg:h3 boards">
            <?php foreach ($users_wishlists as $users_wishlist) : ?>
            <?php
                $token = $users_wishlist['wishlist_token'];
                $name = $users_wishlist['wishlist_name'];
                ?>
            <?php /* <pre><code><?php print_r($users_wishlist); ?></code></pre> */ ?>
            <li>
                <?php if( $name ) : ?>
                <a href="/my-materials/view/<?php echo $token; ?>">
                <?php echo $name; ?>
                </a>
                <?php else : ?>
                <a href="/my-materials">
                Main board
                </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list-reset m0 p0 uppercase lg:h3">
            <li>
                <a href="/my-account/">My account</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/my-account<?php echo wc_logout_url('/') ?>">Log out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
-->
<form id="yith-wcwl-form" action="<?php echo $form_action ?>" method="post" class="woocommerce">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'yith-wcwl-form', 'yith_wcwl_form_nonce' ) ?>
    <!-- TITLE -->
    <?php
        do_action( 'yith_wcwl_before_wishlist_title', $wishlist_meta );
        
        if( ! empty( $page_title ) ) :
        ?>

    <a href="/my-materials/manage" class="btn dark-grey hover:black right">All Boards</a>
    <?php if( count( $wishlist_items ) > 0 ) : ?>
    <a href="#" class="btn dark-grey hover:black right" data-edit-board>Edit Board</a>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="wishlist-title <?php echo ( $is_custom_list ) ? 'wishlist-title-with-form' : ''?>">
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_title', '<h2 class="h1 blue lh2 mt2 mb0 p0">' . $page_title . '</h2>' ); ?>
        <?php /* if( $is_custom_list ): ?>
        <a class="btn button show-title-form">
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_edit_title_icon', '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>' )?>
        <?php _e( 'Edit title', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; */ ?>
    </div>
    <?php if( $is_custom_list ): ?>
    <div class="hidden-title-form">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $page_title ?>" name="wishlist_name"/>
        <button class="button">
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_save_wishlist_title_icon', '<i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>' )?>
        <span>
        <?php _e( 'Save', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' )?>
        </span>
        </button>
        <a class="hide-title-form btn button">
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_cancel_wishlist_title_icon', '<i class="fa fa-remove fa-fw"></i>' )?>
        <span>
        <?php _e( 'Cancel', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' )?>
        </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
        endif;
        
        do_action( 'yith_wcwl_before_wishlist', $wishlist_meta ); ?>
    <?php /* ?>
    <ul class="products columns-4">
        <?php if( count( $wishlist_items ) > 0 ) :
            $added_items = array();
              foreach( $wishlist_items as $item ) :
                global $product;
            
                $item['prod_id'] = yit_wpml_object_id ( $item['prod_id'], 'product', true );
            
                if( in_array( $item['prod_id'], $added_items ) ){
                  continue;
                }
            
                $added_items[] = $item['prod_id'];
                $product = wc_get_product( $item['prod_id'] );
                $availability = $product->get_availability();
                $stock_status = $availability['class'];
            
                  if( $product && $product->exists() ) :
                    ?>
        <li class="product">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product', $item['prod_id'] ) ) ) ?>">
                <?php echo $product->get_image() ?>
                <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cartproduct_obj_title', $product->get_title(), $product ) ?></h2>
                <?php do_action( 'yith_wcwl_table_after_product_name', $item ); ?>
            </a>
            <?php if( $is_user_owner ): ?>
            <div class="product-remove">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_from_wishlist', $item['prod_id'] ) ) ?>" class="remove remove_item_from_wishlist" title="<?php _e( 'Remove this product', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ?>">&times;</a>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $available_multi_wishlist && is_user_logged_in() && count( $users_wishlists ) > 1 && $move_to_another_wishlist && $is_user_owner ): ?>
            <select class="change-wishlist selectBox-">
                <option value=""><?php _e( 'Move', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ?></option>
                <?php
                    foreach( $users_wishlists as $wl ):
                     if( $wl['wishlist_token'] == $wishlist_meta['wishlist_token'] ){
                      continue;
                     }
                    
                    ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $wl['wishlist_token'] ) ?>">
                    <?php
                        $wl_title = ! empty( $wl['wishlist_name'] ) ? esc_html( $wl['wishlist_name'] ) : esc_html( $default_wishlsit_title );
                        if( $wl['wishlist_privacy'] == 1 ){
                         $wl_privacy = __( 'Shared', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' );
                        }
                        elseif( $wl['wishlist_privacy'] == 2 ){
                         $wl_privacy = __( 'Private', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' );
                        }
                        else{
                         $wl_privacy = __( 'Public', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' );
                        }
                        
                        // echo sprintf( '%s - %s', $wl_title, $wl_privacy );
                          echo sprintf( '%s', $wl_title );
                        ?>
                </option>
                <?php
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
            </select>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php
            endif;
            endforeach;
            
            else: ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php */ ?>
    <?php  ?>
    <!-- WISHLIST TABLE -->
    <table class="shop_table cart wishlist_table" data-pagination="<?php echo esc_attr( $pagination )?>" data-per-page="<?php echo esc_attr( $per_page )?>" data-page="<?php echo esc_attr( $current_page )?>" data-id="<?php echo $wishlist_id ?>" data-token="<?php echo $wishlist_token ?>">
        <?php $column_count = 2; ?>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php if( $show_cb ) : ?>
                <th class="product-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="bulk_add_to_cart"/>
                </th>
                <?php
                    $column_count ++;
                      endif;
                    ?>
                <?php if( $is_user_owner ): ?>
                <th class="product-remove"></th>
                <?php
                    $column_count ++;
                    endif;
                    ?>
                <th class="product-thumbnail"></th>
                <th class="product-name">
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_view_name_heading', __( 'Product Name', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?></span>
                </th>
                <?php if( $show_price ) : ?>
                <th class="product-price">
                    <span class="nobr">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_view_price_heading', __( 'Unit Price', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?>
                    </span>
                </th>
                <?php
                    $column_count ++;
                    endif;
                    ?>
                <?php if( $show_stock_status ) : ?>
                <th class="product-stock-status">
                    <span class="nobr">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_view_stock_heading', __( 'Stock Status', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?>
                    </span>
                </th>
                <?php
                    $column_count ++;
                    endif;
                    ?>
                <?php if( $show_last_column ) : ?>
                <th class="product-move"></th>
                <?php
                    $column_count ++;
                    endif;
                    ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                if( count( $wishlist_items ) > 0 ) :
                 $added_items = array();
                    foreach( $wishlist_items as $item ) :
                        global $product;
                
                     $item['prod_id'] = yit_wpml_object_id ( $item['prod_id'], 'product', true );
                
                     if( in_array( $item['prod_id'], $added_items ) ){
                      continue;
                     }
                
                     $added_items[] = $item['prod_id'];
                     $product = wc_get_product( $item['prod_id'] );
                     $availability = $product->get_availability();
                     $stock_status = $availability['class'];
                
                        if( $product && $product->exists() ) :
                         ?>
            <tr id="yith-wcwl-row-<?php echo $item['prod_id'] ?>" data-row-id="<?php echo $item['prod_id'] ?>">
                <?php if( $show_cb ) : ?>
                <td class="product-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item['prod_id'] ) ?>" name="add_to_cart[]" <?php echo ( ! $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>/>
                </td>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if( $is_user_owner ): ?>
                <td class="product-remove">
                    <div>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_from_wishlist', $item['prod_id'] ) ) ?>" class="remove remove_from_wishlist" title="<?php // _e( 'Remove this item', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ?>">&times;</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product', $item['prod_id'] ) ) ) ?>">
                        <!-- THIS IS GRABBING THE IMAGE SUCCESSFULLY -->
                        <?php echo $product->get_image() ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cartproduct_obj_title', $product->get_title(), $product ) ?></h2>
                        <?php do_action( 'yith_wcwl_table_after_product_name', $item ); ?>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <?php /* ?>
                <td class="product-name">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product', $item['prod_id'] ) ) ) ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cartproduct_obj_title', $product->get_title(), $product ) ?></a>
                    <?php do_action( 'yith_wcwl_table_after_product_name', $item ); ?>
                </td>
                <?php */ ?>
                <?php if( $show_price ) : ?>
                <td class="product-price">
                    <?php
                        $base_product = $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ? $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max' ) : $product->get_price();
                        echo $base_product ? $product->get_price_html() : apply_filters( 'yith_free_text', __( 'Free!', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) );
                        ?>
                </td>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if( $show_stock_status ) : ?>
                <td class="product-stock-status">
                    <?php echo $stock_status == 'out-of-stock' ? '<span class="wishlist-out-of-stock">' . __( 'Out of Stock', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) . '</span>' : '<span class="wishlist-in-stock">' . __( 'In Stock', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) . '</span>'; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if( $show_last_column ): ?>
                <td class="product-move">
                    <!-- Date added -->
                    <?php
                        if( $show_dateadded && isset( $item['dateadded'] ) ):
                        echo '<span class="dateadded">' . sprintf( __( 'Added on : %s', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ), date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $item['dateadded'] ) ) ) . '</span>';
                        endif;
                        ?>
                    <!-- Add to cart button -->
                    <?php if( $show_add_to_cart && isset( $stock_status ) && $stock_status != 'out-of-stock' ): ?>
                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <!-- Change wishlist -->
                    <?php if( $available_multi_wishlist && is_user_logged_in() && count( $users_wishlists ) > 1 && $move_to_another_wishlist && $is_user_owner ): ?>
                    <div class="product-move-trigger">
                        <!-- <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/plus-white.svg" alt="" class=""> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-move-dropdown">
                        <h3>Move to Board</h3>
                        <select class="change-wishlist selectBox- select">
                            <option value=""><?php _e( 'Choose...', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ?></option>
                            <?php
                                foreach( $users_wishlists as $wl ):
                                 if( $wl['wishlist_token'] == $wishlist_meta['wishlist_token'] ){
                                  continue;
                                 }
                                
                                ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $wl['wishlist_token'] ) ?>">
                                <?php
                                    $wl_title = ! empty( $wl['wishlist_name'] ) ? esc_html( $wl['wishlist_name'] ) : esc_html( $default_wishlsit_title );
                                    if( $wl['wishlist_privacy'] == 1 ){
                                     $wl_privacy = __( 'Shared', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' );
                                    }
                                    elseif( $wl['wishlist_privacy'] == 2 ){
                                     $wl_privacy = __( 'Private', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' );
                                    }
                                    else{
                                     $wl_privacy = __( 'Public', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' );
                                    }
                                    
                                        if ( $wl_title == 'My Materials' ) {
                                          $wl_title = 'Main board';
                                        }
                                    
                                    // echo sprintf( '%s - %s', $wl_title, $wl_privacy );
                                        echo sprintf( '%s', $wl_title );
                                    ?>
                            </option>
                            <?php
                                endforeach;
                                ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!-- Remove from wishlist -->
                    <?php if( $is_user_owner && $repeat_remove_button ): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_from_wishlist', $item['prod_id'] ) ) ?>" class="remove_from_wishlist button" title="<?php _e( 'Remove this product', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ?>"><?php _e( 'Remove', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php
                endif;
                endforeach;
                else: ?>
            <tr class="empty">
                <td colspan="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_count ) ?>" class="wishlist-empty"><?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_no_product_to_remove_message', __( 'No items have been added to this board yet', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                endif;
                
                if( ! empty( $page_links ) ) : ?>
            <tr class="pagination-row">
                <td colspan="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_count ) ?>"><?php echo $page_links ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endif ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_count ) ?>">
                    <?php if( $show_cb ) : ?>
                    <div class="custom-add-to-cart-button-cotaniner">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'wishlist_products_to_add_to_cart' => '', 'wishlist_token' => $wishlist_token ) ) ) ?>" class="button alt" id="custom_add_to_cart"><?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_custom_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add the selected products to the cart', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ( $is_user_owner && $show_ask_estimate_button && $count > 0 ): ?>
                    <div class="ask-an-estimate-button-container">
                        <a href="<?php echo ( $additional_info || ! is_user_logged_in() ) ? '#ask_an_estimate_popup' : $ask_estimate_url ?>" class="btn button ask-an-estimate-button" <?php echo ( $additional_info ) ? 'data-rel="prettyPhoto[ask_an_estimate]"' : '' ?> >
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_ask_an_estimate_icon', '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>' )?>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_ask_an_estimate_text', __( 'Ask for an estimate', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php
                        do_action( 'yith_wcwl_before_wishlist_share', $wishlist_meta );
                        
                        if ( is_user_logged_in() && $is_user_owner && ! $is_private && $share_enabled ){
                         yith_wcwl_get_template( 'share.php', $share_atts );
                        }
                        
                        do_action( 'yith_wcwl_after_wishlist_share', $wishlist_meta );
                        ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <?php  ?>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'yith_wcwl_edit_wishlist_action', 'yith_wcwl_edit_wishlist' ); ?>
    <?php if( ! $is_default ): ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $wishlist_token ?>" name="wishlist_id" id="wishlist_id">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php do_action( 'yith_wcwl_after_wishlist', $wishlist_meta ); ?>
</form>
<?php do_action( 'yith_wcwl_after_wishlist_form', $wishlist_meta ); ?>
<?php if( $show_ask_estimate_button && ( ! is_user_logged_in() || $additional_info ) ): ?>
<div id="ask_an_estimate_popup">
    <form action="<?php echo $ask_estimate_url ?>" method="post" class="wishlist-ask-an-estimate-popup">
        <?php if( ! is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
        <label for="reply_email"><?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_ask_estimate_reply_mail_label', __( 'Your email', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?></label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="reply_email" id="reply_email">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if( ! empty( $additional_info_label ) ):?>
        <label for="additional_notes"><?php echo esc_html( $additional_info_label ) ?></label>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <textarea id="additional_notes" name="additional_notes"></textarea>
        <button class="btn button ask-an-estimate-button ask-an-estimate-button-popup" >
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_ask_an_estimate_icon', '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>' )?>
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_ask_an_estimate_text', __( 'Ask for an estimate', 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' ) ) ?>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know this script cannot be directly copied as it is looking through product variables knowing which product it is looking through, I need to write something similar that will look inside the wishlist instead of inside the product.

I think I know what I need to do, I just have no idea how to do it.

I have tried simple stuff I predicted wouldn't work before even implementing it. Trying to guess shortcodes / scouring the web for a list of shortcodes.

### Edit

Attempting to achieve this using 'simplehtmldom'...

I have downloaded and installed simplehtmldom then called it into the file:

```
<?php 
    $simplehtmldom = get_template_directory() . "/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php";
    include_once($simplehtmldom);
?>
```

Then gone on to try find the image within the wishlist by gathering the src of the first product in that wishlist:

```
<?php
    $boardlink = YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url( 'view' . '/' . $wishlist['wishlist_token'] );
    $html = file_get_html($boardlink);
    $wishlistimage = $html->find('.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail', 0)->src;
?>
```

The variable $boardlink value has been taken from the href within the section:

```
<a title="<?php echo $wishlist['wishlist_name'] ?>" class="wishlist-anchor" href="<?php echo YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url( 'view' . '/' . $wishlist['wishlist_token'] ) ?>">
```

So technically should / could work...

However, I get a range of errors:

`Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /home/example/public_html/development/wp-content/themes/bolt/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php on line 136`

`Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/example/public_html/development/wp-content/themes/bolt/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php on line 136`

`Warning: file_get_contents(https://development.example.com/my-materials/view/9OW01M6785H9/): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/example/public_html/development/wp-content/themes/bolt/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php on line 136`

This site doesn't have a valid SSL as it is just a staging dev site. The live site does have an SSL.

I think the main issue is with the wishlists being private to the user, I don't think we are able to scrape from these pages.

Comment: This won't work anyway, you would need to pass the users' cookies to see their wishlist. It can probably be done from the frontend with jquery but it's not a great approach IMHO.

Comment: Do you happen to know how the first page (ctrl + f 'WHERE I CAN SEE A WORKING EXAMPLE OF PULLING THE IMAGE FROM A PRODUCT THROUGH') manages to use the image within that collection of products? I imagine I need to engineer some kind of similar use of code that can achieve the results I need.

Comment: No, I don't know anything about that plugin sorry.

Comment: Just found my own question on Google, was like finally someone else has asked this... 11 months with no luck :c